# LG Optimus L5 e610 randomly reboots

Tags: recovery-mode, unbricking, boot-loop, lg-optimus-l5

I have got the phone of my sister in law. It is a LG Optimus L5  e610. While trying to flash CM it has been bricked. It is constantly rebooting after media scanning. It reboots even in the bootloader (CWM 6.2.8). The bootlaoder shows that the sdcard can't be mounted. The time the phone stays in android is to short to use adb.

The phone has been rooted using [this guide](http://www.hackmyandroid.com/root-your-lg-optimus-l5-e610-easily/236). [This guide](http://www.hackmyandroid.com/clockworkmod-cwm-touch-recovery-for-lg-optimus-l5/4073) has been used to flash CWM.

Well hence I can neither use adb to replace anything in the filesystem nor use the recovery to install a zip.

Is there any way to get this phone back working?

Comment: If it's re-booting on MediaScanner: does it have a SDCard inserted? If so, try booting without the card bein inserted. We already had the case with a broken card/file system on the card being the cause of exactly that behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the difference in unlocked bootloaders between e610 and e612. Finally I ended up using the few seconds before the reboot to write the backed up bootloader and recovery back via dd. Wow I hardly often do backups, but this time it was quite helpful.

Comment: It would really help if you explained exactly how you did that. I believe I am experiencing a similar issue.